# PNGJ: cannot add metadata with own key

Tags: png

I need to add metadata during creation of png which I do as follows:

```
private byte[] createData(BufferedImage image, String metaData, float dpi) {
     ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     final int width = image.getWidth();
     final int height = image.getHeight();
     final boolean alphaChannel = image.getAlphaRaster() != null;

     ImageInfo imageInfo = new ImageInfo(width, height, 8, alphaChannel);
     PngWriter writer = new PngWriter(bos, imageInfo);
     writer.getMetadata().setText("mykey", "xxxx");
     writer.getMetadata().setDpi(dpi);
     convertToRGB(image, writer);
     writer.end();

     return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

When immediately reading it back, no value with that key can be found:
    PngReader reader = new PngReader(is);
    String mrv = reader.getMetadata().getTxtForKey("mykey")

Pdi metadata however is set. Using something known in place of my key, like PngChunkTextVar.KEY_Comment does not help either.
I debugged writing and and at writer.end() the value with my key is there.

What am I doing wrong? How to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turned out something was missing in my reading code, namely:

```
reader.readSkippingAllRows();
```

After that my code works.